# Python while loop wont increment the variable

Tags: python, selenium, loops, web-scraping

I am scraping a website and I used their url in order to paginate/get next values. I created an infinite loop so that it wont stop since the data in there are too many. But I dont know why my variable wont increment inside my loop. Also i want to break the infinite loop if there is no data rendered in the json `results`

Here is my code

```
pageNumber = 0
while True:

    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.get('https://reversewhois.domaintools.com/?ajax=mReverseWhois&call=ajaxUpdateRefinePreview&q=%5B%5B%5B%22whois%22%2C%222%22%2C%22VerifiedID%40SG-Mandatory%22%5D%5D%5D&to='+str(pageNumber))
    time.sleep(3)
    pre = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("pre").text
    data = json.loads(pre)
    table = data['results']
    tables = pd.read_html(table,skiprows=1)

    df = tables[-1]

    # print(df.to_string(index=False))
    pageNumber = pageNumber + 1 //it always prints 1
    print(pageNumber)
    continue // i want to loop again with the incremented pageNumber value
```

I think i did it wrong. In case, can you tell me what should i do? Thanks.

Comment: According to the code  you posted, the  variable `pageNumber` should increment. I suggest look up to the rest of your code to check for problems if any.

Comment: You don't need the `continue` on your last line - the `while` loop will continue until an exit condition is reached (condition in the `while` statement or `break`).

Comment: i already figured it out. i replaced it to `pageNumber += 1`

Comment: @user001232 in this case `pageNumber += 1` is exactly the same as `pageNumber = pageNumber + 1` so your problem, whatever it is (or was) is totally unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem with how you increment `pageNumber`.
In order to break the look, try:

```
table = data['results']
if not table:
    break
```

Comment: is that what i need to use if there is no table found?

Comment: `table`, in your case, equal to data['results']. You can replace it with: `if data['results']`

Comment: okay thanks for this. and i think my loop problem was solved.

Comment: Happy to help :) 
What was the problem with your loop?

Comment: i just replaced it to `pageNumber += 1`

Comment: do you know how to access every column and a value in a dataframe?

Comment: There are many ways. One of them is iterating using `df.iteritems()` but it would be better to ask it as a different question :)